# Multiple updates causing data corruption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 update statements as below: I am using SQL Server 2012

```
DECLARE @Duetoday DATETIME = GETDATE()

UPDATE A
SET APPRL_DUE = CASE WHEN MTNG_DT_SCHD IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(D,25,MTNG_DT_SCHD) ELSE APPRL_DUE END   
FROM #1 A

UPDATE A
SET Days_Due = CASE WHEN DT_APPROVED IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,MTNG_DT_SCHD,DT_APPROVED) ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,@Duetoday,APPRL_DUE) END
FROM #1 A
```

As you can see Days_Due is based on the value of Approval Due. For Eg: Approval due for a record used to be 10/22 before the first update, Days_Due in that case would be 11, now lets say approval due is 10/29 after the first update but Days Due is still 11 instead of 18.

In both dev and QA environments this is not causing an issue but our production server has parallelism set and may be causing the second update to run before or during the first update?

I know I can combine both the update statements into one. What I need to know is how can this be handled without combining the update statements and also how can it be tested in either dev or QA?

Thanks.

Comment: Parallelism wont cause second update to run before first..can you please elaborate on what is the data corruption issue here

Comment: If these are your actual queries, it is not actually possible for the second statement to run before the first one, parallelism or no. SQL is a strictly sequential language. The statements *themselves* may exploit parallelism, but that doesn't cause a semantic difference. You may have to be more precise about what you're actually doing, and expecting. Are these statements executing independently in their own sessions?

Comment: Again, if this is your actual code (not a simplification or textual combination of multiple queries that execute separately) parallelism is *not* your problem -- the statements *cannot* execute in an interleaved or altered order, so you can immediately discount that as a possibility and focus on your actual data.  If you believe parallelism *within* the queries is an issue (there *have* been bugs, occasionally) tack on `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to both queries to force the use of sequential plans. But I doubt this will change anything.

Comment: Another useful thing to do is rewrite your `UPDATE`s as `SELECT`s, with the existing columns and your new value next to each other, so you can debug your actual input/output. You should assume the problem is with your query, not the server, as that's simply the most likely explanation. Another thing to verify is that you aren't (accidentally or deliberately) running multiple instances of your client code while failing to put your combined updates in a transaction -- that *will* cause interleaving of updates and possible problems. (Even so, individual statements will still be atomic.)

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I run manually in production (by taking out the query from the sp and running in a new window) or in dev or staging.

Comment: Take out the part that is not repeatable and make it repeatable (`GETDATE()`, make it a constant value). Backup and restore the production database on staging/dev so you're sure you have the same data (and the same stored procedure, quite important). Try the stored procedure vs. separate query approach. If you *still* have a difference in results, you may have found a very interesting problem, but I suspect something more mundane can be shaken loose.

Comment: Another silly thing to check is whether you're interpreting output dates correctly -- formats may differ between servers and applications. The logic of the queries will not be affected, assuming of course they're using `DATETIME` columns and not strings. (On second thought, that's actually a pretty big assumption. Make sure it's true.)

Comment: I have already tried all of the methods you have suggested. Both our DBA's here all say the same thing you guys are all saying - its not possible, but since the same query is running without any issues in dev, staging or manually I suspect parallelism is the only culprit.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't, though -- are you saying your dev or staging machines are actually single core? Are those even *sold* anymore? :-P Otherwise, I can guarantee you they too are using parallelism. Recreate the stored procedure from scratch. Use SQL Server Profiler to capture execution plans for both cases. Try `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. Restart SQL Server. Compare versions to see if you're missing a SP/CU (`SELECT @@VERSION`). There is a difference, somewhere, somehow -- even if it really *was* a bug in SQL Server involving parallelism somehow, you still have a root cause to pinpoint.

Comment: Not to sound like a broken record, but to be perfectly clear: it is impossible (as in, the query optimizer simply *does not work this way*) for a batch of the form `A; B` to *ever* execute B before A, or B during A, or anything else other than to first do A in its entirety, and then do B in its entirety. That's not to say there can't be a bug in SQL Server that prevents `A; B` from having the expected output, but running statements together in a way that violates atomicity would actually take code that just doesn't exist in SQL Server. It's not even a viable optimization path.

Comment: As the code apparently involves temp tables, this is not the whole stored procedure, right? Posting more code might help, as would giving minimal sample data. Queries may have unexpected results when they're non-deterministic, for example, in a way that's not easily reproduced even across identical setups. An update that ever updates a single row multiple times (because of improperly written conditions) has an undefined result. That result may include "happening to usually work the way I expect" without that actually being a guarantee.

Comment: There is more code but its not related to the fields in issue. I know update statements can cause an issue - but in both the cases listed its a whole table update so how can a single row be updated multiple times? I have seen the issue you mentioned when using joins but not on whole table updates.

After much deliberation with the DBA's we have decided on the following approach:

Create a new procedure which will combine both the updates into a single update and load a new table. Compare the 2 tables on a daily basis where Days_Due values do not match for the same records.

Comment: is DT_APPROVED null or not null in the rows where you're getting unexpected results? Is it the same rows that are wrong every time or different ones?

Comment: its for both the NULL and NOT NULL values. Its different rows each day. This table is truncated and inserted each day.